# Flash on Facebook canvas: works in IE, Opera, Safari, not in FF, Chrome

Tags: html, facebook, flash, cross-browser

I'm trying to add a flash game to Facebook page. It works in all browsers, when I test it on my server. But the flash doesn't appear on Facebook in FF and Chrome (IE, Opera, Safari work fine).

```
<embed type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
src="http://www.play-play.com.ua/games/doggy_shelter.swf"
wmode="opaque" quality="high" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true">
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could be security. Try making everything HTTPS (if play-play has a certificate). I see many warnings about loading insecure content. Perhaps Chrome is blocking it.

https://www.play-play.com.ua/games/doggy_shelter.swf does not have a trusted security certificate. **Hence, it is blocked.**

```
    You attempted to reach www.play-play.com.ua, but the server 
presented a certificate issued by an entity that is not trusted 
by your computer's operating system. This may mean that the server 
has generated its own security credentials, which Chrome cannot 
rely on for identity information, or an attacker may be trying 
to intercept your communications.
```

I see additional errors:

Blocked a frame with origin "https://pageflame.com" from accessing a frame with origin "https://www.facebook.com". The frame being accessed set "document.domain" to "facebook.com", but the frame requesting access did not. Both must set "document.domain" to the same value to allow access.

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'setDefaults' of undefined site-general.js?v=1.0:72
[blocked] The page at https://pageflame.com/view.php?id=194217470685302 ran insecure content from http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js.

Unable to post message to https://s-static.ak.facebook.com. Recipient has origin https://www.facebook.com.

Comment: Thanks for advice. But the problem is that url of the flash object is added dynamically. So we can have both "http" and "https" urls.

Comment: You can't just add the HTTPS and prey it works. You certificate is invalid or self-signed.

Comment: Suppose, the flash is on https server. Will it be shown on Facebook in this case?

Comment: The certificate is bad though. Just open https://www.play-play.com.ua. it should throw up a big red "do not enter" in almost any browser. There's no such thing as an HTTPS server. HTTPS is Secure Socket Layer Protocol, and for machines to trust your certificate, it has to be signed by a major issuer.

Comment: It's not "getting shown on facebook" the iframe is like a little browser window to your server. Its getting rejected by the browser, not facebook.